# How do I hide the username/password prompt that appears when a [WebMethod] gets called on an invalid session?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have a `.aspx` with a static method decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute and a ScriptManager on the page, so that the WebMethod can be called with `PageMethods.MethodName()`. Forms authentication is enabled.

This works well in all scenarios except where the WebMethod is invoked on an expired session.  When that happens, the service returns HTTP 401 and a username/password dialog pops up!  I would much rather the user be redirected, as they are with any other request (including asynchronous postbacks).  Is there a way to trap that specific condition, or to configure the application to do the right thing when presented with this case?

*edited to correct actual HTTP status code - it's an HTTP 401, not a 403*

Comment: Are you in an intranet environment with an AD domain?

Comment: No; authentication is managed through a custom auth handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We havet the same problem. We resolved this by disabling Windows Authentication on IIS. That is strange, because our application is configured to use FormsAuthentication too.

Comment: This solution works, although there was some trepidation implementing it in our environments because in .Net1.1, disabling Integrated Windows Authentication prevents VS2003 from attaching to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a webservice for your application that could check IsUserAuthenticated() before you call your WebMethod. If it returns false you could then do a redirect in javascript to your login page and avoid the error. Make sure that this web service doesn't require authentication.

The problem is that the AuthenticateRequest event gets processed before your page ever gets control. Which means there is nothing you can do in the codebehind to solve this issue. Because it's the FormsAuthenticationModule which is rejecting the request and returning the HTTP 403.

Comment: What's perplexing me here is that with other http requests, like postbacks (synchronous or otherwise), the FormsAuthenticationModule correctly sends a 302 redirect to the login page. It's only for web requests that the 403 comes back.

Comment: @DDaviesBrackett I wonder if you want to dig into the asp.net source code.